# Jquery Operators

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure how to  use (OR) operator with JQUERY.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selection1')||('#selection2')||('#selection3').click(function(e) {
    $('#thecheckbox').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

});

Is it possible with .click functionto use (||) operator, if possible HOW? Apearently not the way I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selection1, #selection2, #selection3').click(function(e) {
        $('#thecheckbox').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

jQuery supports comma-separated list of selectors, which in this case means that click handler will be applied to all elements having one of the IDs. Here is the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly, you can do this instead,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selection1, #selection2, #selection3').click(function(e) {
        $('#thecheckbox').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: There is an identical answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure this is what you want to do, anyway if it is not the multiple element selection already written by Andrei then maybe you're looking for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var s1 = $('#selection1'),
    s2 = $('#selection2'),
    s3 = $('#selection3'),
    selection = s1.length !== 0 ? s1 : s2.length !== 0 ? s2 : s3.length !== 0 ? s3 : null;
    selection.click(function(e) {
        $('#thecheckbox').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```